# SQL Server missing tables and stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, object

I have an application on a client's site that processes data each night, last night SQL Server 2005 gave the error "Could not find stored procedure 'xxxx'". The stored procedure does exist in the database, has the right permission as far as I can tell, the application runs fine in other nights as well.

In previous occasions, the SQL Server has also gave error saying 'database object not found', and refers to a table in the database that does exists.

So, on rare occasions, the server thinks certain stored procedures and tables does not exist in the database. The objects it refers to are often ones that are frequently used.

Is the database somehow corrupted, is there some sort of repair/health check I can do?

Comment: Can you check the connection logs to verify that its connecting to the correct database with the appropriate user?

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the schema-qualified name of the object: dbo.StoredProcedure. If the schema changes on you (as it can, depending on who's calling whom), then  your lookup changes.

Comment: In addition to permissions, you may also want to double check under which schema the objects are defined and whether this is the default schema of the account that the client application uses (assuming that it does not explicitly specify schemas in the database calls).

Comment: The stored procedures and tables are owned by dbo, and users's default should be dbo as well.

The application runs automatically each night, so pretty sure the user is the same each time. Not sure why it would work for most nights, but fails on a few occasions.

Comment: Are there any other scheduled tasks/management jobs running around the same time?  Sounds like some other process might be interfering but only on the rare occasions where the process runs longer than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using SQL Database Recovery tool (you can download a trial for free) at http://www.mssqldatabaserecovery.com/. It uses high-end scanning mechanisms to ensure in-depth scanning of damaged database and complete data retrieval and it's really easy to use I think. That may be able to tell you what is causing the issues. I know messed up stored procedures have the potential to corrupt your whole database when they go missing or seeminly dissappear like in your case and then it gets ugly.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Along with other problems, the client ended up moving to a new server...